# How to generate GraphJSON from Neo4j::ActiveModel using jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, neo4j, graph-databases

A frontend library used to render graph data in the browser [alchemy.js](http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy) requires data in the [GraphJSON](https://github.com/GraphAlchemist/GraphJSON) format, which mainly consists of a `nodes` and `edges` top-level keys.

Consider a graph of `Services` that can have `dependencies` (and thus `dependent_services`):

```
class Service
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  has_many :out, :dependencies, type: :DEPENDS_ON, model_class: :Service
  has_many :in, :dependent_services, origin: :dependencies, model_class: :Service
end
```

Retrieving the node data in the jbuilder template works like a charm:

```
nodes = ([service] + service.dependencies + service.dependent_services).uniq
json.nodes nodes do |node|
  json.id node.id
  json.name node.name
  json.type node.class.to_s
  json.url "#{url_for(node)}.json"
end
```

Is there a neat way to retrieve the **list of edges (Relationships)** between the nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a relatively elegant solution, so just in case anyone else is looking for this:

```
# Collect all relations into flat array
relations = [service.dependencies, service.dependent_services].map {|r| r.rels}.flatten
# Collect relation into edges array
json.edges relations.map do |edge|
  json.source edge.start_node_id.to_s.to_i
  json.target edge.end_node_id.to_s.to_i
  json.caption edge.type
end
```

Of course the second part is `jbuilder` specific, but most importantly theres the `.rels` property that holds a list of all outgoing/incoming relations.

I'm using the `neo4j` gem @9.0.7 for this, documentation can be found here: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/wiki/Relationship